# How do I re-architect my model types to reduce code replication

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have 3 model types:

```
public class BankA_Transaction : BanKTransactionMetaData
{
    public string GROUPName { get; set; }
    public string ACC_ID { get; set; }
    public string ACCOUNT_NO { get; set; }
}


public class BankB_Transaction : BanKTransactionMetaData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ACC_ID { get; set; }
    public string ACCOUNT_NO { get; set; }
}

public class BankC_Transaction : BanKTransactionMetaData
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string ACC_ID { get; set; }
    public string ACCOUNT_NO { get; set; }
}
```

Note: The actual property lists are much longer

All of which inherit some fields needed when saving into the database.

```
public class BanKTransactionMetaData
{
    public String BankName { get; set; } 
}
```

These models get filled with records from a file sent by the bank and then saved to a database.
As part of this save I convert the records to JSON as that is required by the database.

```
public void SaveBankA(BankA bankA)
{
      bankA.BankName = "Bank_A";
      string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bankA_Transaction, Formatting.Indented);

Code for saving...
```

At the moment I have a different methods for SaveBankA, SaveBankA and SaveBankB.

It seems to me that this is code replication and that I should get all the models to inherit better in order to use a base type? instead of each named type.

I've read up on Abstract and Virtual classes as I suspect that's what I need but I can't work out how to plug it together.

I can't just use Object in SaveBankA as I need to add .BankName.

Is there a better architecture to reduce code replication?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need something like this?

In base service class:

```
protected void SaveBankTransaction(BankTransactionMetaData tran)
{
    string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tran, Formatting.Indented);
    // additional saving code
}
```

In child service classes:

```
public void SaveBankA(BankA bankA)
{
    bankA.BankName = "Bank_A";
    base.SaveBankTransaction(bankA);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a couple of interfaces, one for your meta data (`IBankData`) and one for your bank transaction details (`IBankTransaction`). The `IBankData` interface will maintain a reference to the `IBankTransaction` interface. This should also allow you to add additional banks when needed, e.g. Bank D.

```
public interface IBankData
{
    string BankName { get; }
    // ... additional bank meta data properties
    // ...
    IBankTransaction Transaction { get; set; }
}

public interface IBankTransaction
{
    [JsonProperty("ACC_ID")]
    string AccountId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("ACCOUNT_NO")]
    string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    // ... additional shared bank transaction properties
    // ...
}
```

FYI, I chose to use the `JsonProperty` attribute to control the name for the JSON key, this allows the class properties to be named according to best practices without affecting the JSON property names.

Next implement the interfaces for each bank you will be working with. In each bank add the additional properties that will only apply to each implementation, i.e. since the `GroupName` property is only used by `BankA`, this property will be added to the `BankA` class and not the interface. The same goes for any other bank specific properties.

**Bank A**

```
public class BankA : IBankData
{
    public string BankName => "BankA";
    public IBankTransaction Transaction { get; set; }
}

public class BankATransaction : IBankTransaction
{
    // Bank A specific properties
    [JsonProperty("GROUPName")]
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    // ... additional Bank A specific properties
    // ...

    // interface implemented properties
    public string AccountId { get; set; }
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
}
```

**Bank B**

```
public class BankB : IBankData
{
    public string BankName => "BankB";
    public IBankTransaction Transaction { get; set; }
}

public class BankBTransaction : IBankTransaction
{
    // Bank B specific properties
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // ... additional Bank B specific properties
    // ...

    // interface implemented properties
    public string AccountId { get; set; }
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }        
}
```

**Bank C**

```
public class BankC : IBankData
{
    public string BankName => "BankC";
    public IBankTransaction Transaction { get; set; }
}

public class BankCTransaction : IBankTransaction
{
    // Bank B specific properties
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    // ... additional Bank B specific properties
    // ...

    // interface implemented properties
    public string AccountId { get; set; }
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
}
```

**JsonConverter**

Since the `IBankTransaction` is a property within the `IBankData` this will change your JSON structer. You may not want this, to retain your structure, a `JsonConverter` can be implemented on the `IBankData` interface. This will remove the *Transaction* object in the JSON and move the child properties under the JSON root.

```
public class BankJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken t = JToken.FromObject(value);
        if (t.Type != JTokenType.Object)
        {
            t.WriteTo(writer);
        }
        else
        {
            JObject o = (JObject)t;
            JProperty transactionProperty = o.Properties().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "Transaction");
            o.Remove("Transaction");
            JToken token = transactionProperty;
            foreach (JToken ct in token.Children())
            {
                foreach (var prop in JProperty.FromObject(ct))
                {
                    o.Add(prop);
                }
            }
            serializer.Serialize(writer, o);
        }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Unnecessary because CanRead is false. The type will skip the converter.");
    }
    public override bool CanRead => false;
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
         return objectType.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IBankData));
    }
}
```

**Usage**

For the usage example I've created a few test functions to prep the data and added `SaveBank` method that you can relocate in your actual code as it would make sense for your solution.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        string bankATransJson = GetBankATestJsonInput();
        BankATransaction bankATransaction = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BankATransaction>(bankATransJson);
        BankA bankA = new BankA();
        bankA.Transaction = bankATransaction;
        Console.WriteLine(SaveBank(bankA));
        // output:
        // {
        // "BankName": "BankA",
        // "GROUPName": "g54321",
        // "ACC_ID": "A01",
        // "ACCOUNT_NO": "A1111"
        // }

        string bankBInputJson = GetBankBTestJsonInput();
        BankBTransaction bankBTransInput = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BankBTransaction>(bankBInputJson);
        BankB bankB = new BankB();
        bankB.Transaction = bankBTransInput;
        Console.WriteLine(SaveBank(bankB));
       // output:
       // {
       // "BankName": "BankB",
       // "ACC_ID": "B02",
       // "ACCOUNT_NO": "B2222",
       // "Name": "Bank_Of_B           
       // }

        string bankCInputJson = GetBankCTestJsonInput();
        BankCTransaction bankCTransInput = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BankCTransaction>(bankCInputJson);
        BankC bankC = new BankC();
        bankC.Transaction = bankCTransInput;
        Console.WriteLine(SaveBank(bankC));
        // output:
        // {
        // "BankName": "BankC",
        // "ACC_ID": "C03",
        // "ACCOUNT_NO": "C3333",
        // "FullName": "C Bank"
        // }
    }

    public static string SaveBank(IBankData bankData)
    {
        // when calling the serialize object method, we pass our BankJsonConverter
        string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bankData, Formatting.Indented, new BankJsonConverter());
        // this example just returns the JSON text
        // but you would implement your save logic as needed
        return jsonText;
    }

    private static string GetBankATestJsonInput()
    {
        var obj = new { ACC_ID = "A01", ACCOUNT_NO = "A1111", GROUPName = "g54321" };
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
    }

    private static string GetBankBTestJsonInput()
    {
        var obj = new { ACC_ID = "B02", ACCOUNT_NO = "B2222", Name = "Bank_Of_B" };
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
    }

    private static string GetBankCTestJsonInput()
    {
        var obj = new { ACC_ID = "C03", ACCOUNT_NO = "C3333", FullName = "C Bank" };
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
    }
}
```